# How to rename the file before upload to the Dropbox on Android (Programmatically)

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api, android-file

I have use the dropbox SDK to upload multiple images to dropbox.

I found that if I upload the same file name it will replace the old one.

My idea is to rename before upload.

Note : I don't want rename the local file just want to rename the file that uploaded to dropbox

Anyone has an idea?

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is "name conflict" so this may be a solution

```
DropboxAPI.UploadRequest putFileRequest(String path, InputStream is, long length, String parentRev, boolean autoRename, ProgressListener listener)
```

force boolean autoRename to true

However, I still want to rename before upload to dropbox on Android programmatically

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. The first parameter is the path... just change it to whatever you want?